# IIS: DirectoryEntry Exception: "access denied"?

Tags: wpf, iis, .net-4.0

When I am creating the DirectoryEntry as:

```
string path = string.Concat("IIS://", serverName, "/W3SVC/1/Filters");
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path);
```

I am getting the exception : "Access Denied".
I am using WPF windows application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this application under an account that has administrative privileges to the server you are creating virtual directories.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but here I am not creating virtual directory. I want to access the filters applied on that Virtual Directory.

Comment: @Sandy, you need to be administrator in order to access anything in IIS.